# How to load all DLLs used by NetCore at program startup

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, .net-5

I am developing wpf at dotnet5.

DevExpress components have been added for development.

In the process of development,
When you call a subwindow containing a DevExpress control
It takes about 2 seconds to load the required DLL.

After loading is complete, if you close the window again and call again, it will be called immediately.

It is thought of as the time it takes to load the DLLs related to the DevExpress control.

I installed DevExpress related packages through Nuget.
Is there a way to preload all required package-related DLLs when the program is run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start running the static initialisers for types in specific assemblies. Though you probably want to start that in a background thread.

```cs
foreach (var a in
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .Where(a => a.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyCompanyAttribute>()?.Company == /* todo */ )
    )
{
    foreach (var t in a.GetTypes())
        RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(t.TypeHandle);
}
```

But there may be further lazy initialisation that would speed up these DevExpress controls.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.

Sorry for not understanding your idea.

Can you ask for a more specific explanation?

Comment: Running class constructors forces all `static` variables and constructors to be run, which can't hurt. You'd need to use some kind of profiling tool to measure where the time is really going and to guess how you might cause that initialisation to run without creating a gui control.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of.  First note that assembly loading and JIT are happening on first call and so loading the assemblies is only part of the work.

You can build a single file app https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file and optionally use Ahead-of-time compilation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/ready-to-run

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I tried compiling and running based on this, but I still have the same performance issue. T_T In MainWindows Create a SubWindows object, The goal is to eliminate the performance problem that occurs when you call it for the first time.